# How To Scan Nearby Bluetooth devices in iOS using CoreBluetooth?

Tags: ios, swift, core-bluetooth

**I used this code for CoreBluetooth devices in swift iOS. It scans devices with repetition and displays only one device or unknown device name. I cannot find my phone name or earbud's name during the scan. Can anyone specify what I am doing wrong.**

```
override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
       centralManager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil)

    }

func centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager) {
        print("Central state update")
        
        if central.state != .poweredOn {
            print("Central is not powered on")
        } else {
            print("Central scanning for", particleLEDServiceUUID);
            centralManager?.scanForPeripherals(withServices: nil)
        }
    }

    func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber) {
  
          print("Discovered \(peripheral.name ?? "")")
        
    }
```

Comment: Not sure It'll help, but can you add an option
"let options = [CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey : true]
central.scanForPeripherals(withServices: nil, options: options)"

And if you have serviceUUID, why you are sending nil?

Comment: Which serviceUUID is require to show available bluetooth devices.